# node express mysql connection error handling optimization

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a lot of code inside my routes like this:

```
connection.query("query one", function(err, rows){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        connection.query("query two", function(err, rows){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                connection.query("query three", function(err, rows){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }else{
                        connection.query("query four", function(err, rows){
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            }else{

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I end up with so many "if(err)". I wonder if there is a more optimized way to handle these errors efficiently at the same time. I can write a function with callback to handle all these errors :

```
var connection2 = function(connection, query, callback){
    connection.query("query one", function(err, rows){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            callback(rows);
        }
    });
}
```

By this way I can get rid of all the "if(err)"s.
Are there any better solutions, ideas, or references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Promises, then your code would look like this

```
query('...').then(rows => {
}).then(query('...')).then(rows => {
}).then(query('...')).then(rows => {
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

You need a query function that is returning a Promise for that

```
const query = (sql, values) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // maybe use a connection Pool and log the statement for debugging
    connection.query(sql, values, (err, rows) => {
      if (err)
        return reject(err)
      resolve(rows)
    })
  })
}
```