# How to handle a Fatal connection Error in node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, error-handling

I am attempting to make a connection to a MySQL database using Express and Mariadb. The IP for the database changes while I move the PI that it is connected to from the office to my Home. If I don't change the IP before hand then it obviously can not connect to the database, this is fine and a known issue but I want to be able to handle this error without having Node throw a fatal error and shut down

```
app.get("/db", (req, res) => {
  console.log("ping to db!")
  MariaPool.getConnection()
  .then((conn) => {
    conn.query("SELECT * FROM devTable")
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        res.json(data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Poor SQL format")
    })
    .finally(() => {
      conn.end()
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("No connection")
    res.json({
      err: error
    })
  })
});
```

Above I attempt to make a connection to the Database, when the IP is wrong it goes to the catch block and logs `No Connection` as it should, however afterwards a second fatal error is thrown

```
text: 'Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1002ms',
  sql: null,
  fatal: true,
  errno: 45012,
  sqlState: '08S01',
  code: 'ER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
```

this causes the Node server to shutdown. Try as I may I am  unable to find a way to handle this error.

My initial  thought is to somehow stop the attempts to make the socket creation once it goes into the catch block but I'm not sure if that is possible.

I've taken a look at [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67451203/how-to-handle-mysqlstore-connection-error) but `app.use` does not solve my problem

Tried the implementation of my own `Promise` as documented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699385/node-express-mysql-connection-error-handling-optimization) and   it still does not handle the fatal  error

To sum it up, is it possible to handle fatal errors such as this to allow the program to continue?